# Code is saying "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

This is the code:

```
print ("____________________________")
            print ("Advanced calculator selected")
            print ("Experimental! May break.")
            print ("NOTE: Does not work with variables... yet.")
            print ("Key:", "\"()\" mean parenthesis", "\"^\" mean exponent", "\"*\" means multiplication", "\"/\" means division", "\"+\" means addition", "\"-\" means subtraction", sep="\n  ")
            option = "3(5+3)" #input("Equation to solve:").strip()
            option2 = list(option)
            count = -1
            c = True
            while count < len(option2) - 1:
                if c is True:
                    count += 1
                    c = False
                elif c is False:
                    c = True
                if option2[count] == " ":
                    option2.pop(count)
                    count -= 1
                    continue
                elif option2[count] in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and option2[count + 1] == "(":
                    option2.insert(count + 1, "*")
                    count += 1
                elif option2[count] in ["(", ")", "*", "/", "+", "-"]:
                    continue
                elif option2[count] == "^":
                    option2.pop(count)
                    option2.insert(count, "**")
                elif str(option2[count]).isalpha() is True:
                    print ("Option not recognized, restarting")
                    counting.Calculator.Advanced()
                else:
                    continue
            print (option2)
            answer = "".join(option2)
            print (answer.isascii())
            answer = eval(str(answer))
            print (answer)
            input()
```

I can't figure out why it's saying this. It's supposed to just spit out that equation in `option`
as a number but it's instead giving an error.

I have tried using `str()`, I've tried `map()`. I have 0 clue what is wrong, ChatGPT didn't help either, and neither did documentation on the function.

Comment: You're trying to evaluate `3(5+3)`.  In Python, that is going to try to call the function `3` with the argument `8`.  Of course that's bogus.  You need a multiply operator in there.

Comment: It helps to include the full traceback message so that we can see where the error is raised. And try to pare down the example to a short, running snippet that fails in the same way.

Comment: "I can't figure out why it's saying this." That is because you did not follow the appropriate [steps to verify what actually happens as the code runs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), perhaps by [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/). Note well that we do not write answers here that "find the bug" - you [are expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to locate the problem first by following those steps, and to showcase it in a [mre].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Every element of `option2` is a string.  That means this statement will never be true:

```
                elif option2[count] in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and option2[count + 1] == "(":
                    option2.insert(count + 1, "*")
                    count += 1
```

Instead, you want to know if the string contains ASCII digits:

```
                elif option2[count].isdigit() and option2[count + 1] == "(":
                    option2.insert(count + 1, "*")
                    count += 1
```

I don't know what your `c` flag is trying to, but it seems pointless.  Why don't you just do the more Pythonic way:

```
for char in option:
```

You can build a new string to be evaled, if you need to, although `eval` is inherently dangerous.

Comment: The c thing for the case of spaces, also, I don't use .isascii because I don't want letters in it.

Comment: I never said `isascii`.  I said `isdigit`.  With that change, your code works for me.  And Python doesn't care about spaces in expressions.

Comment: Once again: please read [answer], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum or help desk**. The purpose of answering questions on Stack Overflow **is not** to get the OP's code to work, but to contribute to a searchable reference Q&A library. If you wish to provide this kind of personalized assistance, please use any of the countless other sites on the Internet that are actually designed for it, such as https://discuss.python.org/ or https://reddit.com/r/learnpython.